# Color pairs in ncurses not working properly in classes

Tags: c++, colors, console, ncurses

I'm making a basic terminal-app engine with ncurses. I have made a basic window class, which stores the window you are working with, and allows you to write on it. Now, I'm doing a ColorWindow class, which inherits from BasicWindow, and should allow you to write with colors. Per abstraction, I'm initializing the color pairs I need in one of the methods of the class, here is the example code:

EDIT: I'm writing here all code

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class ColorWindow : public BasicWindow {
private:
    int npairs;
    bool canColor;
    void initializePairs() {
        init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(3, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(4, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(5, COLOR_MAGENTA, COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(6, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(7, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);

        npairs = 8;
     }

   public:
    ColorWindow() {
        if(has_colors()) {
           initializePairs();
           this->canColor = true;
        }
        else {
           this->canColor = false;
        }
    }

    ColorWindow(int he, int wi, int stx, int sty) : BasicWindow(he, wi, stx, sty) {
         if(has_colors()) {
             initializePairs();
             this->canColor = true;
         }
         else {
             this->canColor = false;
         }
     }

    int addColorPair(int foreground, int background) {
         if(foreground < 0 || foreground > 7 
              || background < 0 || background > 7)
              return -1;

         init_pair(npairs, foreground, background);
         npairs++;

         return npairs-1;
    }

    bool ColorWindow::writeStringWithColor(int x, int y,const char* message, int pair) {
        if(!isInLimits(x, y))
           return false;

        if(pair >= npairs) 
          return false;

        if(canColor)
          return false;

        wattron(getContainer(), COLOR_PAIR(pair));
        mvwprintw(getContainer(), x, y, message);
        wattroff(getContainer(), COLOR_PAIR(7));
     }

    bool changeColor(int color, int r, int g, int b) {
         if(!can_change_color())
             return false;

         if(color < 0 || color > 7 || r < 0 || r > 1000 
             || g < 0 || g > 1000 || b < 0 || b > 1000)
             return false;

         init_color(color, r, g, b);

         return true;
    }

};

class BasicWindow {
   private:
    WINDOW* container;
    int startx, starty, height, width;

   public:
    BasicWindow() {
      this->height = 20;
      this->width = 84;
      this->starty = (LINES - height) / 2;  /* Calculating for a center placement */
      this->startx = (COLS - width) / 2;
    }

    BasicWindow(int he, int wi, int stx, int sty) {
      this->height = he;
      this->width = wi;
      this->starty = sty;
      this->startx = stx;
    }
    

    WINDOW* createNewContainer() {
          this->container = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);

          wrefresh(this->container);        /* Show that box        */

          return getContainer();
    }

    WINDOW* getContainer() {
          return this->container;
    }

    bool writeString(int x, int y, const char* message) {
        if(!isInLimits(x, y))
            return false;

            mvwprintw(this->container, x, y, message);
        }


    void refreshContainer() {
        refresh();
        wrefresh(this->container);      /* Show that box        */
    }

    void destroyWindow() {
         wborder(this->container, ' ', ' ', ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ');
        
         wrefresh(this->container);
         delwin(this->container);
   }

    bool isInLimits(int x, int y) {
         if(x < 0 || x >= this->width-1) {
             return false;
         }
         if(y < 0 || y >= this->height-1) {
              return false;
         }
         return true;
};
```

And here is the main:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <ncurses.h>
 #include "windows.h"

 int main() {
    ColorWindow cw = ColorWindow(20, 80, 0, 0);


    initscr();          /* Start curses mode        */
    cbreak();           /* Line buffering disabled, Pass on
                        * everty thing to me        */
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    start_color();

    WINDOW* container;

    container = cw.createNewContainer();
    cw.writeStringWithColor(0, 10, "Hello everyone in color!!", 2);
    cw.refreshContainer();
    sleep(2);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

It initializes the color mode, but shows nothing, as if the pair selected was the BLACK BLACK.

Comment: The example still doesn't compile.

Comment: Finally, I have uploaded ALL code and makefile to this github repo. https://github.com/Shirkamdev/physic_simulator

Answer (score 0):

Running the code (and tracing it using ncurses' [debug-trace feature](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_trace.3x.html)), there is only one call to `init_pair`, using a pair number which appears to come from an uninitialized value, e.g., `7978` in this part of the listing:

```
called {init_pair(0x193e250,7978,5,7)
return }0
```

and a quick scan of the sources shows that corresponds to this method:

```
/* PUBLIC METHODS */
int ColorWindow::addColorPair(int foreground, int background) {
        if(foreground < 0 || foreground > 7
                || background < 0 || background > 7)
                return -1; 

        init_pair(npairs, foreground, background);
        npairs++;

        return npairs-1;
}
```

and `npairs` is never set to zero in the constructor.

You might find `valgrind` useful for seeing this type of problem.

Comment: Well, it was an error while copying the code. I have edited so now it shows all my code.